# What does `keyof any` do?

Tags: typescript

As I know, for any type T, the `keyof T` will be public property names of T, and then I see  `keyof any` which make me confused. Can I just simplify `keyof any` to `any` ?

Comment: keyof any is just a subset of any, i.e. key can only be string, number, symbol etc.

Comment: Consider using PropertyKey instead of keyof any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `keyof any` isn't `any`.  It is `string | number | symbol`:

```
type PropKey = keyof any
// type PropKey = string | number | symbol
```

[The `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) results in a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all key types which are known to be allowable for the type.  So `keyof any` is asking for all possible key types, since [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) allows you to index into it with any valid key whatsoever. Not all types are valid keys, though, so `keyof any` is just `string | number | symbol` instead of something like [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown):

```
declare const x: any;
x.str; // okay
x[123]; // okay
x[Symbol("")] // okay
x[new Date()] // error
x[false] // error
```

An equivalent type to `keyof any` is [provided in the TypeScript standard declaration files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/95d89216418d339339499e1228f83f48f6ea22c6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L105) as `PropertyKey`:

```
declare type PropertyKey = string | number | symbol;
```

---

Generally speaking you would probably use `PropertyKey` instead of `keyof any`, if you're only interested in supporting recent TypeScript versions.

The reason why you might see `keyof any` is that before TypeScript 2.9, the `keyof` operator would only return types assignable to `string`.  Starting with TypeScript 2.9, [`keyof` supports `number` and `symbol` key types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types) as well.  And `PropertyKey` itself was also introduced in TypeScript 2.9.

That means if you have any TypeScript code which needs to support versions both before and after TypeScript 2.9, you can use neither `PropertyKey` nor `string | number | symbol` to properly [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) key types.  But you *can* use `keyof any`; in TypeScript 2.8 and below, `keyof any` returns just `string`, while afterward it returns `string | number | symbol`.  So you can write something like

```
type DateHolder<K extends keyof any> = { [P in K]: Date };
```

and it will work in both cases.  It's been a while since TypeScript 2.8, though, and many [breaking changes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes) have occurred since then, so using `keyof any` is probably not necessary.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAaQiKBeKBrNCBmUAhgHYgCwAUAPTVSiSyIpqZQDOwcAliQOZQAPlBIBXALYAjCHCEcQUhABsqVACYQAxkqJxomhCU5QAHgC5iZANxUTAOk5wrUWlATYiFSiYDaARgAmAGYAXWdXd09bHwBlBUllAAoAImSAShCXOkivXxIIAHcoABEiYAhEjKyoGUQ4aPwiJXYITNdahHrKaJM2ugAeAFpB+gALbnYoCbcPdElRYDcSJTmtIlEWy3Rp0SMEXbUqRIBvIgs-AF80n17qoZHcEAIoU4sxKRkLqcnkomSAGhECEWpC8VAY0FK5QAEsoNHB+sgaiZyiQ1JNHs9QQA+NjHKA+GBTEhQZAhCxQ6AXGzdShAA)

Comment: That's clear for me now, thanks!